# How do I split all the data in str in python?

Tags: python, string

I have to split the values from a txt file. Problem is I can't split all the data and return. I don't even know which str method will accomplish my goal. Here's what I want to do:

Given data:

```
1.02.34.35.55.33.64.64.46.74.36.67.45.68.53.75.54.45.23.67.24.98.67.45.23.75.2
```

what I want:

```
1.0
2.3
4.3
5.5
.
.
.
.
.
5.2
```

Comment: how are you getting "given data"?  can you post the code you're using to read the text file in order to define "given data"?  also, post a few lines of the text file, as they appear in the file itself.

Comment: Will all numbers always be exactly one digit followed by a decimal point followed by exactly one digit? If not, if you see "1.012.3", should that become "1.0 12.3", or "1.01 2.3"?

Comment: No i don't have that. All I'm getting is a text file containing those value.

Comment: @Taha all on one line?

Comment: @Kevin : No,  I want exact as I've showed above

Comment: @dbliss Yes, I've showed exact what I'm getting

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: this question is total nonsense. why on earth would anyone ever save data in a text file that way?

Comment: @dbliss Sometimes we don't decide, which format our data arrives in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '1.02.34.35.55.33.64.64.46.74.36.67.45.68.53.75.54.45.23.67.24.98.67.45.23.75.2'
for i in range(0,len(s),3):
    print(s[i:i+3])
```

Answer (score 3):

[chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) the string into groups of three, then re-join.

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

s = '1.02.34.35.55.33.64.64.46.74.36.67.45.68.53.75.54.45.23.67.24.98.67.45.23.75.2'

print "\n".join(chunks(s,3))
```

Result:

```
1.0
2.3
4.3
5.5
...
5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest answer is to split the string up 3 characters at a time. This assumes that each number is exactly two digits with a decimal point in between.

```
>>> data = '1.02.34.35.55.33.64.64.46.74.36.67.45.68.53.75.54.45.23.67.24.98.67.45.23.75.2'
>>> [data[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]
['1.0', '2.3', '4.3', '5.5', '5.3', '3.6', '4.6', '4.4', '6.7', '4.3', '6.6', '7.4', '5.6', '8.5', '3.7', '5.5', '4.4', '5.2', '3.6', '7.2', '4.9', '8.6', '7.4', '5.2', '3.7', '5.2']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use regexp.

```
import re
test='1.02.34.35.55.33.64.64.46.74.36.67.45.68.53.75.54.45.23.67.24.98.67.45.23.75.2'
num = re.compile('\d\.\d')
list_of_num = re.findall(num, test)
```

Internally it does the same thing - the regex engine matches against each character. So can't say this is more performant. You don't have to look at loops though.